What should a tab's `aria-controls` refer to when inactive content isn't rendered?
I have an app with some tabs, but since it is rendered clientside it seems much more straightforward to render only a single (i.e. the currently selected) tab panel content at a time.
In cases like this, what should the aria-controls target be for the inactive tabs? Can I reuse the identifier of the single/shared panel across all tabs without causing issues for those relying on the ARIA metadata?
As a concrete example (using Preact hooks, hopefully the variable names are self-explanatory regardless) something like this:
const MyApp = ({ items }) => {
  const [selectedItemKey, selectItemKey] = useState(items[0].key);
  const selectedItem = useMemo(() =>
    items.find(d => d.key === selectedItemKey),
  [items, selectedItemKey]);

  return (
    <div class="my-app">
      <div class="sidebar" role="tablist">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <button type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-selected={item.key === selectedItemKey}
            aria-controls="single-element-container0"        <------- ???
            onclick={evt => selectItemKey(item.key)}
          >{item.name}</button>
        )}
      </div>
      <div id="single-element-container0" class="details-display" role="tabpanel">
        <h2>{selectedItem.name}</h2>
        <p class="intro">{selectedItem.intro}</p>
        <p>{selectedItem.details}</p>
        <p class="seeAlso">{selectedItem.moreInfo}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

The potential problem here is that for all items they will either be rendered into the  #single-element-container0 div, or not rendered at all. So I only have one element identifier to share among all N tab buttons — is that okay?
From a rendering perspective it seems more efficient to generate the content only for the active tab, rather than rendering it all out and having to add CSS to hide the inactive ones. But aria-controls seems to want to reference all potentially available specific tabpanels even when they're not otherwise needed in the DOM. Is there a best practice for this situation?

Not an expert, but from what I understand, that should be fine. aria-controls doesn't concern itself with active/inactive, just which element has its contents controlled by another. You should be able to have multiple tabs point at the same container w/out issue, the container is indeed controlled by all 3.

Best practice is to follow the correct pattern, by having different tabpanels for each tab. If you don't want to render a tabpanel's contents until it's needed, that should be fine. But it would be appropriate to have each tabpanel wrapper element rendered at the start and persist in the dom.
